# Unique product creation

Tags: commerce

I'm trying to figure out the best way to create a product on Commerce 2.x.

What we have is physical products that don't have variation, so basically each product is a stand-alone.
What would be the best practice for creating a product?

Currently, I created (in this order):

1. Product Variation type (with fields that represent product properties)
2. Product type (where I select the variation type)

I didn't create any attributes though.

Would this be the right way of doing it?

Also for my second question, I created a Product list page with Views and selected Table view. However, I can't find "add to cart" field nowhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you've configured the entities properly. Nothing requires you to make use of attributes, so if you don't need them, you don't have to make them. : )

Re: the field formatter for Views to display an Add to Cart form, it hasn't been developed yet.